# CSS Causing Website To Crash On Mobile Device?

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, crash

I'm new to web design and have managed to create a simple website that I'm currently testing to see how it runs. I have no problems getting it to run on a computer but when I test it on a mobile device it often crashes. I've noticed that it runs well on most mobile web browsers except for Google Chrome.

After doing some research I've found many people talking about how they had trouble getting their websites to run based on the CSS they had used. I've tried fiddling around with my code to see if I can isolate the issue but have been unable to find the solution.

Could the mobile Google Chrome issue have anything to do with the `-webkit-transform:` script that I used? Could the issue have arisen from the `display: block` or `display: none` script that I used? Any knowledge that one could share would be very much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" charset="utf-8">
    
<body>
    
<style>html{visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;}</style>
    
<title>MORIKOBOSHI・</title>
      
<div class="page-wrap">
     
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">About This Website</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="#">Bibliography</a></li>
    
            
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; position: inline;">
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Custom Google Search" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;">
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style="padding-left: 5px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 50px; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center;">
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html">    

</form>
</div>    

    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:morikoboshi.com' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
 
</script>


<script>
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
} 

</script>

</ul>    
</nav>
</header>     
               
<div class="setsumei">
    
 <br><br><h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 40px;">◯◯◯◯</h1>
    <br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;"></p>
    
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Author: ◯◯◯◯</p>
 <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">Photos/Videos Taken：◯◯◯◯/◯◯/◯◯</p>
    
 <br><br><p style="text-align: justify; font-size: 16px;">    
    
    #
 </p>    
        
</div>
        
<br><br><div class="image">
    
  <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
 
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>

 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
 <br><br><a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#" width="90%"></a>
    
</div>
    
<br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">MORIKOBOSHI© | <a href="#">日本語</a></footer>

</div>
</div>
      
<style>
    
html {visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;}
    
.body{background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;}
    
 .searchbar{float: right;}
    
 .image{text-align: center;}
    
 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}
    
 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}
    
 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 20px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
        

 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
    
 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}
    
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}
    
 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;
    
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }
    
    
    
 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}

        
        
 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;
        
    }
    
/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;
        
        
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
    
 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }
 
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    
 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }
    
 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}
    
 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}
    
/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 
    
 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
</style> 
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't heard of CSS crashing a website... What exactly do you mean by "crashing"? If your site's actually crashing, the browser should give you an error like 500, 404 etc. What error is the browser giving you?

Comment: What's happening is after viewing a few pages the website seems to freeze. I'm unable to click on any of the links (including those on the menu bar), I'm unable to go back to previous pages that I viewed, and sometimes content on certain parts of the page will disappear. I only seem to be having this issue on the mobile version of Google Chrome.

Comment: What are these properties for? `html { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; }` When applied, it will make your entire page white and non-interactive.
`

Comment: I was noticing a white flicker between each page when they were loading, so I added this line of code to help try and get rid of it.

Comment: First, no browser has needed the webkit prefix for those in many years. Second, note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. None of that will fix your problem, though.

Comment: CSS can indeed crash a website in chrome. It's happening right now on our site (I don't maintain that code so I cannot fix it). It happened earlier too and it was a single line of CSS that crashed the whole thing and made Chrome use up all available memory. Happened on multiple computers. Mobile was unaffected. It was display:table used in a menu that did it.